# How can I get the text of an askstring?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like the text of the askstring so that you can specify the port in the gui.

Is that even possible?

I also try this **connection.get()**

```
    msg1 = tkinter.Tk()
    msg1.withdraw()
    msg1.geometry("300x300")

    connection = simpledialog.askstring("Connection", "Please choose a Port", parent=msg1)

    connect_ = connection.get()

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = f"{connect_}"
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `connection`, not `connection.get()`:

```
connect_ = connection
```